# cannot install Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 on Windows 7 (32-bit)

Tags: flash, adobe, extract, builder

I have downloaded the Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 Installer, but when I double click it, it began to extract files, then prompted "error occurred while extracting files, try re-downloading Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 Installer".

I googled this problem, this post http://forums.adobe.com/thread/837849 says that Adobe Flash Builder extracts files to Desktop by default, and we can change the extracting location by

"*Fortunately, there's a workaround:
- open a command window, and cd to the location of the self-extracting exe you downloaded
- run the exe with the /d option (destination), that allows you to customize the path to which the installer is extracted.

In my case, the full syntax string looked this way:
FlashBuilder_4_5_LS10.exe /d c:\customExtractionFolder*"

I followed the above instruction, unfortunately, I still got the same error. Could you please help me, thanks!!! I have been puzzled by this problem for several days!

Edit: I found the post for the same problem at here http://forums.adobe.com/message/4172311, it was not solved...

Answer (score 0):

OK, let me answer my own question.

I tried to install Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 on different platforms and different computers (windows 7, 32/64bit), and I got the same error! (Really frustrated and annoyed!) Then, occasionally, I restarted a computer and ran it again, it successfully extracted and installed!

I don't why! Adobe!!!